# How to group by two columns in pandas where the combination of the two is unique

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, unique, distinct

I have a dataframe of two columns that together are unique, that I would like to group by and be able to show the result. For example:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'label': ['A','A','B','B','B','C','E','E'],
     'value': [30,30,40,40,40,0,10,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

results in

```
  label  value
0     A     30
1     A     30
2     B     40
3     B     40
4     B     40
5     C      0
6     E     10
7     E     10
```

Notice how all A's are 30, B's are 40, etc.
If I try to `groupby` both:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['label','value'])
print(grouped)
```

results in `<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x00000208BD8470D0`.

I'd really like to just get rid of these duplicate lines in the dataframe.

My goal is to get the resulting dataframe:

```
  label  value
1     A     30
2     B     40
3     C      0
4     E     10
```

Comment: df.drop_duplicates()/ grouped.head(1)

Comment: That's awesome, thank you @BENY !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[head](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-head) can be used to get the first `n` rows from each group:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'label': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'E'],
     'value': [30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 0, 10, 10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df.groupby(['label', 'value']).head(1))
```

---

[drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html#pandas-dataframe-drop-duplicates) can be used to remove duplicate rows from the DataFrame as a whole:

```py
print(df.drop_duplicates())
```

Output For Both:

```
  label  value
0     A     30
2     B     40
5     C      0
6     E     10
```

---

Assuming there are other columns in the df and duplicate `'label', 'value'` pairs are the only values that should be considered the subset flag can be used:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'label': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'E', 'E'],
     'value': [30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 0, 10, 10],
     'third': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['label', 'value']))
```

Output:

```
  label  value  third
0     A     30      1
2     B     40      3
5     C      0      6
6     E     10      7
```